# Rename Files that are in many sub folders and with the same name say data.csv, then combine then concatenate

Tags: excel, csv

I have a data → The data contains such as Name, email, Phone etc.

The files are divided into folders based on countries such as →
 Australia
 New Zealand
 USA
 UK
 Ireland and all other Countries.

In this country Folder, a file is kept, which is normally of the sort 1.csv that means the name is same in all the folders 1.csv in USA, Canada, Australia or perhaps any other country, for example.

See this Video → http://screencast.com/t/rwuE9RoXD.

Operation 1→ Change the name of the file, which is CSV or excel sort of format to country format such. Precisely this image → http://screencast.com/t/XUgqNx3U, but I have to make it in such a manner that it can handle any extension in excel. For example, in Australia folder, the "1.csv or 1.excel" should be changed to australia_1.csv and in zimbabwe folder, it should be changed to zimbabwe_1.csv. Similarly for other countries. Then collect these modified names extension in one folder named common. Got It?

Operation 2 → Combine all the modified Files into one big File. I am showing you structure of the sample 1.csv file see this video → http://screencast.com/t/O1dJmeRJALDZ. We will need 3 columns to be combined = Domain Name, Full Name, and Email. While doing this combination it will be advisable If 4th column can be created which will have entry like from where the entry is coming such as Australia_1, Zimbabwe_1

Operation 3 → Concatenation result in a new column like this →

> `Full Name<Email> = James Bond <james.bond@gmail.com>`

, for example that means name and email concatenated in the above format that I showed you.

All three steps are doable through some command in window or excel?

Comment: If this is a one-time deal, use a bulk-renamer such as [Métamorphose](http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/) for Operation 1. Further, can you have the source write the files as desired?

Comment: No the source will not write the file as desired because they sell data in bulk and they follow this format, but they didn't answered why.

Comment: I have downloaded the software, but will this software work because every country has its own folder and under each of these folders the file that is kept has the same name in all countries(125 total countries) → The file name is 1.csv

Comment: I saw few videos it worked, but there are other operations pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer and I am writing the answer to my own question so that someone may find it helpful.

**The solution for Operation 1** → As suggested by ti7 this software [Métamorphose](http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/)  can help rename the files in a subfolder(or Perhaps the main folder).

If you want to move the contents of a source directory and all of its sub-directories to a single destination directory (i.e. flatten the folder structure), it's very easy and you don't even need to bother with the command line.

Just go to the top-level source folder (whose contents you want to copy), and in the Windows Explorer search box type * (just a star or asterisk). This will display every file and sub-folder under the source folder. Now just sort by Type to group all files together, select them all, then cut/copy and paste in the destination dir.

If you have hidden and system files as well, under Organize → Folder and search options → View tab make sure Show hidden files... is selected, and Hide protected operating system files is unchecked. [citation](https://superuser.com/questions/523816/easiest-way-to-extract-the-contents-of-many-folders-at-once)

**Solution for Operation 2 →**
If the column structure is same then this [software](https://bulkfilemerger.com/) can help in the combination or merger.

**Solution for Operation 3** → This [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tkmkEl_Q8Q) will help Concatenate.